# Azure Service Bus - Token issuer is invalid

Tags: java, spring, azure, token, azureservicebus

I am trying to create a simple SpringBoot application that receives message from Service Bus, but when I try to connect with DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder I am getting this error:

```
Failed to create receive link test_cd989b_1701894453220
status-code: 401, status-description: InvalidIssuer: Token issuer is invalid. 
TrackingId:fbfe2a23-dec8-4d1f-b695-4ce9548b8c9a_G31, SystemTracker:NoSystemTracker, 
Timestamp:2023-12-06T20:27:37, errorContext[NAMESPACE: -. ERROR CONTEXT: N/A, PATH: $cbs, REFERENCE_ID: 
cbs:receiver, LINK_CREDIT: 0]
```

Here is the code that I am using:

```
 public ServiceBusReceiverAsyncClient getSBAsyncClient() {
    ServiceBusReceiverAsyncClient asyncReceiver = new ServiceBusClientBuilder()
            .credential("-", credential)
            .receiver()
            .disableAutoComplete()
            .queueName("test")
            .buildAsyncClient();

    Disposable subscription = asyncReceiver.receiveMessages()
            .flatMap(message -> {
                System.out.printf("Received Seq #: %s%n", message.getSequenceNumber());
                System.out.printf("Contents of message as string: %s%n", message.getBody());

                // Explicitly settle the message using complete, abandon, defer, dead-letter, etc.
                return asyncReceiver.complete(message);

            })
            .subscribe(unused -> {
                    }, error -> System.out.println("Error occurred: " + error),
                    () -> System.out.println("Receiving complete."));

    return asyncReceiver;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried explicitly defining the environment variables AZURE_TENANT_ID, AZURE_CLIENT_ID and AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET. DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder tries a wide variety of authentication sources trying to find a valid configuration, including from the IDE and platform key stores.